# Multi language php script

Tags: php, multilingual

How to create multi language main menu in html/php script
now i have

```
<li>
<a href="{url p='poceni-letalske-karte.html'}">
<span>{t t="Letalske Karte"}</span>
</a>
</li>
```

and

`<option value='EN'>English</option>` which it go to `mysite.com/EN`
i want when user select English language EN code it also change main menu text  how to do that ?
This is website [Letalske karte](http://hotelpedia.si)

I found this script http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html
But i don't know how to set to /EN/  as now in this script is set to `index.php?lang=en`

Comment: Yeah sure, we all speak... whatever dat language is...

Comment: You asked this exact question yesterday. You should edit that question rather than open a new one.

Comment: And what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: @LukaBoltes - for a start, you could do with including your script in the question, rather than a link to a third party website. You're also more likely to get help if you can show that you've tried something, even if it didn't work - as it is now, your question reads like you want someone to do everything for you. Have you added a language <select> to your site? Why doesn't it work? What happens when a user changes the value? What's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My Approach would be to do the following:

Step 1: Setup a folder tree structure like this:

```
Languages
 -en
   -lang.en.php
 -fr
   -lang.fr.php
 -de
   -lang.de.php
```

**keep making new folders with all the other languages you want to support**

Step 2: Create our language files, i will start with `languages/en/lang.en.php`

```
<?php   
  $lang['label']      = 'Value for this label';
  $lang['firstname']  = 'First Name';
  $lang['lastname']   = 'Last Name';
  $lang['phone']      = 'Phone';       
  // ETC
?>
```

you would repeat this for every other language, ill do fr for example `languages/fr/lang.fr.php` . NOTE how the labels stay the same in english

```
<?php   
  $lang['label']      = 'Valeur pour ce label';
  $lang['firstname']  = 'Prénom';
  $lang['lastname']   = 'Nom de famille';
  $lang['phone']      = 'Téléphone';       
  // ETC
?>
```

Step 3: Check if the user has requested a language change, via a url variable

```
<?php
  // Start a Session, You might start this somewhere else already.
  session_start();

  // What languages do we support
  $available_langs = array('en','fr','de');

  // Set our default language session
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';   

  if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){ 
    // check if the language is one we support
    if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs))
    {       
      $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // Set session
    }
  }
  // Include active language
  include('languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');

?>
```

Step 4: you can access your language parts like so and it would change based on what language file is loaded.

```
<?php
  echo $lang['firstname'];
?>
```

hope this helps get you started as an idea

Comment: Thx for code where to put 3rd step ?
Also how could i set to site.com/EN/ ?

Comment: did you plan on having duplicate websites in each folder? EN/FR/DE or did you just want to have it flag a language and redirect to main site?

Comment: my advice, would be to use a query string, like, index.php?lang=EN to capture what language preference the user wants and using htaccess to rewrite those urls as index.php/EN

Comment: How to create htaccess rewrite ?
It needs to be like hotelpedia.si/EN like is now for hotel language selector at the same time i want to be main menu translated
For SEO is same with index.php/en or just /en/  right ? as i would prefer just /en/

Comment: Beautiful solution. This helped a lot. I just replaced $lang with $dict, to avoid confusion with the 'lang' key from the $_GET array.

Answer (score 1):

Used the above code, but session is overwritten every load to EN, so changed it to

```
<?php
// Start a Session, You might start this somewhere else already.
session_start();

// What languages do we support
$available_langs = array('en','zh-cn','es');




if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){
    // check if the language is one we support
    if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs))
    {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // Set session
    }
}



// Set our default language session ONLY if we've got nothing
if ($_SESSION['lang']=='') {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';

}


// Include active language
include('languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your language file is really long, you could break it up by page by adding this above the language include:

```
// for login page
$textpart = 'login';
```

and have the language page split up the array thusly

```
<?php   
switch ($textpart) {
  //login page
  case 'login':
    $lang['label']      = 'Value for this label';
    $lang['firstname']  = 'First Name';
    $lang['lastname']   = 'Last Name';
    $lang['phone']      = 'Phone';
    break;

  //home page
  case 'home':
    // ETC
}

// All pages
   $lang['title']       = 'Title';
   // ETC

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## LM PHP (Language management PHP)

**Multi-language management and support for the PHP.**

---

Sample :

```
<?php
include "LMPHP.php";
/////////////////////////////
$langs = new LMPHP();

$langs -> language_add("en","English");
$langs -> language_add("fr","Germany");

$langs -> language_active("en");
$langs -> word_add("Bye","Good Bye!");
$langs -> word_add("HowAre");

$langs -> language_active("fr");
$langs -> word_add("Bye","Au revoir!");

print_r( $langs -> words );

echo $langs -> word_get("Bye");
```

Code Repository :
https://github.com/BaseMax/LMPHP

Full Sample Code :
https://github.com/BaseMax/LMPHP/blob/master/Sample.php