# Need help implementing a multilingual website using php

Tags: php, html, web, var, multilingual

I am trying to create a multilingual website

I may be going about this the wrong way but here it goes

So just to test first in index.php i have:

```
<?php
$CURRENT_LANG = "en";
require'./includes/essentials/config.php';

include_once'./includes/essentials/header.php';
include_once'./includes/plugins/search-bars/global-nav.php';
include_once'./includes/essentials/footer.php';

php echo $test 
?>
```

in my config.php i have:

```
<?php
if($CURRENT_LANG == "en"){
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gps/includes/language/lang-en.php';
}else{
    if($CURRENT_LANG == "pt"){
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gps/includes/language/lang-en.php';
    }
}
?>
```

in lang-en.php i have:

```
<?php
$test = "Hi";
?>
```

in lang-pt.php i have:

```
<?php
$test = "Olá";
?>
```

The question at hand is how would i make it so that the user can change the var from en to pt so i can have to php files with all the translations needed?

Or is this a really bad way to implement multiple languages?

Comment: `$CURRENT_LANG = "en"` you didn't close this off and will produce a parse error.

Comment: You're also assigning instead of comparing.

Comment: @FunkyFortyNiner Sorry about that, but how do i make it possible for the client to change the $CURRENT_LANG from en to pt?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369947/multi-language-php-script

Comment: Thanks, maybe I need to upgrade my searching skills *scratches head*

Comment: Welcome. No worries. Many times people don't know what to look for, and I too did not know some time ago :) I found that (with other hits) using "how to code a multi lingual site php". *Cheers*

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/szakalq/php-i18n

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-i18n